# Laravel 5.5 Route model binding with customized key name

Tags: php, laravel

I searched a lot of topics related already on SO. I am unable to make it work with the Controller method, but it works when I add it in the route file like this:

Both methods have this in the **Application model aka app/Application**:

```
class Application extends Model
{

    public function getRouteKeyName(): string
    {
        return 'token';
    }
    ...
```

---

so my **routes/web.php**, which works, looks like this:

```
Route::get('/application/{locale}/{application}', function (string $locale, App\Application $application) {
    return view(
        'application.application.main',
        [
            'application' => $application,
            'isLanguageNeeded' => false,
        ]
    );
```

});

---

my **app/Http/Controllers/ApplicationController.php**, which returns *an Application not found* error, looks like this:

```
    public function application(string $locale,  \App\Application $application)
{
    return view(
        'application.application.main',
        [
            'application' => $application,
            'isLanguageNeeded' => false,
        ]
    );
}
```

the **routes/web.php**:

```
Route::get('/application/{locale}/{application}', 'ApplicationController@application');
```

Comment: Just to locate the issue, have you tried using the following as controller method? `public function application(string $locale, string $application) { $application = \App\Application::where('token', $application)->first(); return view(...); }` (or in other words: did you try to load the model manually?)

Comment: yes, I have tried it manually. unfortunately I get the same *Application not found* error

Comment: And you are sure that the link is ok and that you are passing a proper `token` (instead of `id`)? I guess you are aware of what overriding `getRouteKeyName()` does?

Comment: well, it works, when I inline it in routes/web.php

Comment: Then the only thing I can imagine leading to this error is a typo or a wrong namespace somewhere. But just to make sure: The error `Application not found` is a custom one of you? Because normally you'd get a `ModelNotFound` exception or something similar...

Comment: so I cannot var_dump($application);die(); in the controller method, it doesn't even reach it. Also I don't find it in the project, where I add this error. i get 404 in the access logs though.

Comment: Not even when you use `function(string $locale, string $application)`? By the way, `dd($var)` (_dump and die_) is a shortcut for `var_dump($var); die();`.

Comment: not even, when i try it manually. so my guess is routes/web.php is just not correct. it looks good to me though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184178/discussion-between-namoshek-and-metanerd).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just recreated a project. Used dummy names for methods and other.

In ApplicationsController i added:

```
`public function index(string $locale, \App\Application $application)
{
  dd('here');
}`
```

In web routes:
    `Route::get('applications/{locale}/{application}', 'ApplicationsController@index');`

In Application model:

`public function getRouteKeyName() : string
    {
        return 'token';
    }`

Then `php artisan serve`
and in http://127.0.0.1:8000/applications/el/test1
i got a correct response you can try explicit binding
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing#explicit-binding

Also note that 404 response is used when there is no record found. For example if i hadn't an app with test1 token i get 404;

I hope it helps.

Comment: which laravel version is your project?

Comment: it is 5.7 but as far as i know nothing changed in this section from 5.5. I recently updated a project from 5.5 to 5.7 and all worked great in this section without changes. Did you disable any middleware? Laravel uses middleware for route model binding.

Comment: @metanerd namespace in your application model should be like this namespace App;

Comment: I found it, I had added some middleware that i created a long time ago, which i didn't know existed :facepalm:
thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Laravel automaticlly passing request as a first parameter to the controller ... for this  reason you should edit your controller like this :

```
public function application(Illuminate\Http\Request $request ,string  $locale,\App\Application $application)
{
    return view(
      'application.application.main',
    [
        'application' => $application,
        'isLanguageNeeded' => false,
    ]
 );
}
```

Comment: That's not the issue. Laravel will try to bind the function parameters by name. If that doesn't work, the framework will pass them in order. But you don't have to add the `Request` as parameter necessarily.

Comment: yes, I think I had already tried this. same *Application not found* error.